# Is there any such thing as an https storage engine?

Tags: mysql, storage-engine

Maybe I have too much time on my hands, and this may be a stupid idea, but...

I have recently had to download data in table-form from websites, and I got to thinking that it might have been easier, if I could define these "https://..." as tables/views that I could simply query with SELECT. Is this simply stupid?

Comment: Scraping is a field in itself - what happens if  you have multiple tables per page (e.g. Wiki)? I used Weichbrodt's [tool](https://wikitable2csv.ggor.de/) to good effect to get .csv from Wiki pages. The problem I see is that there is no agreed format for every web page to have its tables - some are images also. Still, I'm giving a +1 for a very interesting question and I'd like to see if there are any imaginative solutions out there. A search provides lots of stuff for Wiki, but for other sources, not so  much. I would suggest that there might be a Python solution but not MySQL specific?

Comment: @Vérace I suspect there is no solution that will work in general, but perhaps something that would work with a largish subset of REST APIs? They would have to return things in some format that could be parsed into a table, and support selection on keyword (similar to WHERE ...). Not straightforward, but doable?

Comment: You can try https://data-miner.io/  but for an automated scraping, i think you must program it.

Comment: Please provide a few sample pages with tables you want to grab.  I agree that there should be two steps:  "fetch and convert to CSV", then use the existing MySQL tools for CSV.